# how to handle set of files in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone help to code java to process each word file in a folder having multiple files.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you want to do, and exactly which points you are stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Commons IO is one way, but you can do this without any libraries:

```
public void processFilesIn(File folder){
    File[] contents = folder.listFiles();

    int file = 0;
    while(file < contents.length){
        process(contents[file]);
        file++;
    }
}

private void process(File f){
    if(f.isDirectory()){ //Recursively descend into any folders - optional.
        processFilesIn(f);
    }
    else if(canProcess(f)){ //Write boolean canProcess(File f) so you don't try to process files you aren't interested in.
        //do processing
    }
}
```

You'd call this like so: `processFilesIn(new File("/path/to/folder"));`

Answer (score 0):

To work on all files in a directory you can use the [apache commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library . Listing all files in a directory filtered by the extension (if you want to have the word files only) looks like this :

```
URI dirUri = "your dir as uri";
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(dirUri,new String[] {"doc"}, false);

for(File file : files){
    process(file);
}
```

You can create a `URI`from a directory name by using

```
YourClass.class.getResource(resName);
```

where resName is a classpath-relative path to your directory

Comment: -1 Why use Apache Commons when this functionality exists in the standard Java libraries?

Comment: @Erik Robertson : because its concise. other solurions need extra classes or loops while the commonsIO solution is a single line. its not like its an esoteric lib no one has ever heard about. most probelms can be solved with vanilla SE alone, with more or less extra work. do you dislike commons IO for a reason? -1 seems kinda stern btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file filter (non-recursive example below):

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".doc");
    }
};

for (File f : new File("c:").listFiles(filter)) {
    processWordFile(f);
}
```